# Why isn't this react component that searches github's api not rendering?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, components, github-api

Hi I'm practicing with React by pulling github user info from github's API. I have everything laid out correctly or so it seems, but the component doesn't render for some reason. Here is the code I have:

```
      class GitHubSearch extends React.Component {

constructor( {
    super();
    this.state = {
        username: ''
    }
})

getUser(username) {
    return fetch('https://api.github.com/users/${username}')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        return response;
    })
}
async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let user = await this.getUser(this.refs.username.value);
    this.setState({username: user.login,
        id: user.id,
        url: user.url,
        avatar_url: user.avatar_url,
    });
}

render() {
 let user;

 if(this.state.username) {
    user = 
    <div>
        <p>{this.state.username} <br/> {this.state.id} <br/> </p>
        <img src={this.state.avatar_url}/>
    </div>
 }

return (
    <div className="GitHubSearch">
      <header className="Search-header">
        <h1>Github User Search </h1>
      </header>
    <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
      <input ref='username' type='text' placeholder='username' />
    </form>
            <p className="Search-intro">
                {this.state.username} <br/>
                {this.state.id}
            </p>
    </div>
    );
   }
}

   ReactDOM.render(<GitHubSearch/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

The HTML:

```
      <div id="container">

     </div>
```

The only thing the editor on jsfiddle just says there's syntax errors but I know there aren't any, but it's always good to have another pair of eyes on things. Please let me know if there's something I'm over looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your constructor to fix the syntax error:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {username: ''};
}
```

EDIT

Mistake here too:

```
getUser(username) {
    return fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        return response;
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much Now I see it rendering

Comment: You also need to pass the props. `constructor(props){ super(props); this.state = { username: '' };}`

Comment: I think it has something to do with this: https://api.github.com/users/$%7Busername%7D 404 (Not Found) @SwashataGhosh that's what comes up in the console

Comment: When you use $, you need to use magic quotes like `return fetch(\`https://api.github.com/users/${username}\`);`